# HMS 4.0 game buoy does not show Games.getBuoyClient(activity).showFloatWindow();

Tags: android, game-physics, huawei-mobile-services

Call Games.getBuoyClient(activity).showFloatWindow(); to display the buoy, but the buoy is not displayed.

Has been initialized, the initialization code is

```
JosAppsClient appsClient = JosApps.getJosAppsClient(activity, SignInCenter.get().getAuthHuaweiId());

         appsClient.init();
```

And is executed in the ui thread, what is the cause of the buoy problem.

Comment: Did you call `HuaweiMobileServicesUtil.setApplication(this)` in your Application override? Check the docs: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/game-start

Comment: Thanks,I'll check the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BuoyClient.showFloatWindow interface needs to be called in the onResume of all game interface Activity to display the buoy.
Click to view more: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/game-buoy-v4#h1-1576589973315